Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a constructor
I'm using the web worker package webworkify-webpack. I followed the instructions provided to implement it in my code. The code works perfectly fine in my local development environment, but when I deploy it to production, an error is thrown in the console.
This error is thrown when executing the worker.addEventListener() method : Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a constructor
main:
import work from 'webworkify-webpack';

interface MessageEvent {
  data: unknown;
}

interface Worker {
  addEventListener: (event: 'message', callback: (message: MessageEvent) => void) => void;
}

type Work = (path: string) => Worker;

export const shouldUsePlayerWorkers = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
  console.log('shouldUsePlayerWorkers');
  if (typeof Worker === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    const worker = (work as Work)(require.resolve('../workers/consoleDetector.ts'));
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      worker.addEventListener('message', (result) => {
        resolve(result.data as boolean);
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
  return false;
  }
};



Web worker:
interface Worker {
  postMessage: (...args: unknown[]) => void;
}

const consoleDetector = (worker: Worker) => {
  try {
    console.assert(1, 'Test');
    worker.postMessage(true);
  } catch (e) {
    worker.postMessage(false);
  }
};

export default consoleDetector;

webpack bundler config:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const pathBase = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    asyncChunks: true,
    publicPath: "/v4"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        sideEffects: true,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css|sass)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[local]",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  target: ['web', 'es5'],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', ".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      '@dazn/focus-manager/web': path.resolve('./node_modules/@dazn/focus-manager/web'),
      'core-js': path.resolve('./node_modules/core-js'),
      'animejs': path.resolve('./node_modules/animejs'),
    },
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(pathBase, 'src/index.html'),
      inject: 'body',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};



Please don't name your interfaces the same as native built-ins, e.g. Worker. Also note that package is abandoware that hasn't had a commit in over 5 years.
